# Music playing over the song when i return to the original VC

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, xcode9, swift4, audio-player

I am using xcode 9 and swift 4 for my app. In my app i have music playing in the viewDidLoad. When i exit the view controller to go to another View, it continues to play like it should. How ever, when i return to that view controller the song starts to play again. This song is overlapping the song that first loaded. Do you guys have any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

```
do
{
    let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "APP4", ofType: "mp3")
    try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
}
catch
{
    //catch error
}

let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do
{
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
}
catch
{
}

player.numberOfLoops = -1
player.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It starts playing again, because your `viewDidLoad` is called again, which asks it to play it again. A simplest fix would be to keep a static bool variable to keep track if you have already made this call.

```
static var isMusicPlaying: Bool = false
```

In your `viewDidLoad`, you can put code before the code that calls the play.

```
guard !isMusicPlaying else {
   return
}
isMusicPlaying = true
```

Comment: Although, ideally your code that plays audio should be housed separately  in a manager somewhere.

Comment: I see what you mean, i have put the code in my ViewDidLoad but it comes up with a error on the first and last line. Static member 'isMusicPlaying' cannot be used on instance type 'ViewController'. I have tried putting the static variable in my viewDidLoad as well but i got this error. static properties may only be declared on a type.

Comment: @DaManSeth76 the variable has to be declared outside the `viewDidLoad` function. And should be called with the class name. For example `MyViewController.isPlaying`

Comment: It worked! Thank you for helping me i really appreciate it!